# How to rewrite a link with a parameter to have its own unique link pointing directly to it

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting

I currently have a page like, `https://domainname.com/article.html?id=5`

I'd like a link to somehow point directly to that by either rewriting or redirecting to hopefully achieve a link that looks like it.

`https://domainname.com/article/title-of-article-here`

(I would like to remove the `.html` as well if possible!)

I'm sure I could change the parameter to be by the title instead which I imagine would make this easier but if at all possible keeping the id parameter is what I'm hoping for.

Any help is appreciated! I'm sure there are multiple ways to accomplish this.

I've tried various .htaccess things I've found online, but I am not experienced in writing for it so that is pretty much beyond me at this point.

I imagine a solution (that still uses the id parameter) will take a combination of things, not just .htaccess rewrites.

Comment: Rewriting is basically just string operations on requested paths. That is very convenient, but it cannot somehow magically "guess" the correct ID of a requested resource. So if such an ID is required to send the correct response to the request, then that ID either has to be part of the request somehow (maybe `/article/5/title-of-article-here`?), or it has to be hard coded inside the rewriting directives. If you only have a limited set of such articles and that set is (more or less) static over time, then the second option might be interesting for you.

Comment: Thanks for the comment!
I'm wondering if there's a way to on article creation, create a link that refers to the correct id? That first suggestion is promising though thanks!

Comment: Usually the ID is created as an auto incrementing ID inside the database engine. That means that the entry has to be inserted first, only then the ID is taken. You certainly can create and insert the article, retrieve the ID and use it in a reference during one single request to the server (that is the typical scenario of the "C" in the CRUD principle). But you cannot somehow predict that ID or generate it prior to inserting the article into the database. While that would be possible from a technical view it makes things more complicated. Rely on proven patterns instead.

Comment: For the first option, so if you use references like `/article/5/title-of-article-here`, the rewriting rule you are looking for is probably something like that: `RewriteRule ^/?article/(\d+)/ /article.html?id=$1 [L]`. You just ignore the title in the reference, you are not interested in it from a technical point of view, it only serves as an orientation for humans reading the reference.